# About the number of the elements of a set related with binomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

For $N\in\mathbb N$, let 
$$P_l(N)=\# \{(n,m)|0\le n\le N, 0\le m\le n,\binom{n}{m}\not\equiv 0 \mod l\}.$$
Suppose that $\binom{n}{0}=1$ for $n\ge 0$ and that $\# S$ represents the number of the elements of a set $S$.

Then, here are my questions.

**Question 1** : Find $\lim_{N\to\infty}\log_N P_6(N)$.

**Question 2** : Find $\lim_{N\to\infty}\log_N P_l(N)$ for $l={p_1}^{m_1}{p_2}^{m_2}\cdots {p_s}^{m_s}\ (p_1\lt p_2\lt \cdots\lt p_s)$.

**Motivation** : I've found that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\log_N P_p(N)=\log_p \frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ for any prime number $p$. However, I'm facing difficulty for non-prime-number cases. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146048/about-the-number-of-the-elements-of-a-set-related-with-binomial-coefficients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Douglas Zare on MO.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146048/about-the-number-of-the-elements-of-a-set-related-with-binomial-coefficients